# boostrap 4 validation on select seems not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make validation work on `select` with bootstrap 4 but can't.

Here is what I've tried:

My **Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      "use strict";
      window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() == false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          form.classList.add("was-validated");
        }, false);
      }, false);
    }());

</script>
```

My **HTML**:

```
<form class="container" novalidate="" action="/calc" method="POST" id="myForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="inputGroupSelect01">Power Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="powertype" id="inputGroupSelect01" required="required">
                <option selected>Choose Power Type...</option>
                <option value="1">Single Phase</option>
                <option value="2">Two Phase</option>
                <option value="3">Three Phase</option>
            </select>
            <div class="valid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select power type!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="voltage" >Voltage (U) in V</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="voltage" id="voltage" min="0" step="0.1" placeholder="voltage (U) in V" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill voltage!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="power" >Power (I) in A</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="power" id="power" min="0" step="0.1" placeholder="power (I) in A" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill power!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="phicos" >Phi cosine (Cosφ)</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phicos" id="phicos" min="0" step="0.1" placeholder="phi cosine (Cosφ)" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill phi cosine!</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit">
                <i class="fa fa-code"></i> Calculate
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr>

    <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Result of Power Active</span>
        <input type="text" value="{{result}}" class="form-control is-valid" readonly>
        <div class="valid-feedback">click to calculate</i></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

All input fields validation works except the select one, who display text `valid-feedback` and accept the POST.

Here is a way to make it work? I am not an expert in javascript so maybe you have to manage something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your select is not invalid. The initial option has already been selected. If you don't want that you could do something like below and then the validation message will work.

```js
(function() {
      "use strict";
      window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() == false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          form.classList.add("was-validated");
        }, false);
      }, false);
    }());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<form class="container" novalidate="" action="/calc" method="POST" id="myForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="inputGroupSelect01">Power Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="powertype" id="inputGroupSelect01" required="required">
                <option disabled selected value> select a phase </option>
                <option value="1">Single Phase</option>
                <option value="2">Two Phase</option>
                <option value="3">Three Phase</option>
            </select>
            <div class="valid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select power type!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="voltage" >Voltage (U) in V</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="voltage" id="voltage" min="0" step="0.1" placeholder="voltage (U) in V" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill voltage!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="power" >Power (I) in A</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="power" id="power" min="0" step="0.1" placeholder="power (I) in A" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill power!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="phicos" >Phi cosine (Cosφ)</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phicos" id="phicos" min="0" step="0.1" placeholder="phi cosine (Cosφ)" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill phi cosine!</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit">
                <i class="fa fa-code"></i> Calculate
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr>

    <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Result of Power Active</span>
        <input type="text" value="{{result}}" class="form-control is-valid" readonly>
        <div class="valid-feedback">click to calculate</i></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok! I've added ``disabled selected value`` in initial option and it works. Thanks.